# Frustum culling code architecture

Tags: c++, architecture, frustum

I'm adding frustum culling into my game engine, but I have some design issues regarding the frustum and the cameras.
Should the frustum be a member of the camera, or vice versa ? Should a camera be built from a frustum or should the camera build and maintain it's own frustum ?

Comment: Frustum should be a member of the camera. You should expose it somehow, maybe through constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Make your frustum class independent from any camera implementation - it only requires a combined view-projection matrix to be created. Then, add a frustum instance to your camera class. Think about it - it makes sense to think that a `camera has a frustum` but not the other way around.

---

**Long Answer**

A `Camera` class will typically manage a view and projection matrix. But you usually rely on helper methods from your API to create these matrices, such as `CreateLookAt` or `CreatePerspective`. While it might be possible, I don't think it would be very practical to deduce the view and projection matrices from the frustum. **So I'd forget about building the camera from the frustum**.

As for *how* to build the `Frustum`, I like the way that XNA handles it, which is basically by providing a **constructor that takes a combined view-projection matrix and deduces everything else from there**. This way there's no direct dependency between the frustum and your camera implementation. All it cares about it receiving *some* view-projection matrix from *somewhere*.

Finally, as for whether one class should *contain* the other, my opinion is that, if anything, **your camera class could manage a frustum object and keep it in sync**. I think doing it the other way around would be a bad design choice, because the frustum is a lower level concept than the camera, and the frustum shouldn't have to rely on a specific camera implementation. Or the simple argument that composition should be used to implement `has-a` type of relationships, and it doesn't make sense to say that a `frustum has a camera`.

---

**Example**

In sum, something like this for the frustum class (just to give you an idea, it might have other members and features too):

```
class Frustum
{
public:
    Frustum(Matrix viewProjection);
    void SetMatrix(Matrix viewProjection);

    bool Intersects(BoundingBox box);
    bool Intersects(BoundingSphere sphere);
    bool Intersects(Point point);

private:
    Plane[6] planes;
}
```

With your camera class being something like (once again not a complete example):

```
class Camera
{
public:
    void SetPosition();
    void SetPitch();
    void SetYaw();

    Matrix GetViewMatrix();
    Matrix GetProjectionMatrix();
    Frustum& GetFrustum(); // Or expose the Intersects methods directly

private:
    Matrix viewMatrix;
    Matrix projectionMatrix;
    Frustum frustum;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Also like Xna, ot might be a good idea to publ

Comment: ...expose a public method in the frustum class to update the frustum on a frame by frame basis.

Comment: @SteveH Good point, I've added that detail to the example.

Comment: ... and I managed to misspell frustum 18 times on my answer :)